# Angular unit test, goes over lines of code doesn't count in results

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-test

I tried a lot of things but I just couldn't get the send-results test to work

[image]

I'm running the above testing scripts using

```
nx run libName:test --code-coverage --codeCoverage
```

This is the tested component

[image]

Athe below pice is the last version of the tests I tried. When I'm stepping over the component in debug mode the tests go over each line (line from 40 - 55, for the onNoClick and onSubmit it's the same story it goes over in a different test but then nothing) but then when I run it in the console I get 50%.

Does somebody have any idea why?

[image]

Comment: It seems like it's not going inside of the `subscribe` block and testing the `if (index === 4)`.

Comment: that was also my assumption bug when I ran it in debug it's going there

Comment: Ok, sorry, then I am not sure.

Comment: @AliF50 thanks for trying to help, I appreciate it :)